# Requiring a shared object (.so) file in Love2D with Lua

Tags: lua, require, love2d

Recently, I have wanted to make a [Love2D](https://love2d.org) game and publish it on Steam. I looked around the internet, and I found [luasteam](https://github.com/uspgamedev/luasteam). What luasteam does, is it creates lua bindings for the Steam API. Luasteam, at least for Linux, is distributed with a shared object (.so) file. And when I try to require it (it's in the same folder as my `main.lua`), with `Steam = require('luasteam')` then run `love <FolderName>`, it doesn't work. I get an error message.

[image: error message]

The things is, when I run `love ../<FolderName>` when I am inside the Project Folder, it works.

Now you might ask, "Why don't you just do that all the time?". It's because running it like I did above is only a quick fix. When you make your game a .love file, it runs the way I showed you before and shows me the same error as before this one:

[image: this one]

I've tried changing the `package.cpath`, but to no avail. What would be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify *how* you tried changing `package.cpath`, so it's difficult to say what went wrong, but what you'd need to do is to set it up in a way that allows `luasteam.so` found relative to the location where the Lua interpreter (embedded in Love executable) is launched from.

`love ../<FolderName>` works because you likely put `luasteam.so` into your project folder, so it's found as `./luasteam.so`. If you want to make `love <FolderName>` work, you need to include `<FolderName>/?.so` into your `package.cpath`. Try adding the following line before you do `require "luasteam"`:

```
package.cpath = package.cpath..";<FolderName>/?.so"
```